# Error in HoltWinters ... unused argument (h =

Tags: r, forecasting

Data:

```
data <- c(13,15,13,15,18,44,22,20,35,25,22,26,24,
          26,38,25,32,47,17,23,49,19,22,44,14,18,37)
ts <- ts(data, frequency = 12, start = c(2013,1))
```

I want to forecast 12 months ahead with HoltWinters

```
tsHolt <- HoltWinters(ts, seasonal = "additive")
tsHoltPredict <- HoltWinters(tsHolt, seasonal = "additive", h = 12)
plot(tsHoltPredict)
```

But I am getting:

> Error in HoltWinters(tsHolt, seasonal = "additive", h = 12) : 
>     unused argument (h = 12)

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. The `HoltWinters()` function doesn't have a parameter named `h=` (see `args(HoltWinters)`). Why are you passing that value?

Comment: I'm using this tutorial: http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html#holt-winters-exponential-smoothing, where `h` is supposed to be the prediction window.

Comment: That's for the function `forecast.HoltWinters()`, not `HoltWinters()` as the tutorial shows. Those are different functions.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for clearing that up! Jaehyeon's solution seems to be working

Comment: **h** is used only **ses**,**holt** and **hw** functions from `forecast` package,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `predict()` what you are looking for?

```
tsHoltPredict <- predict(tsHolt, n.ahead = 12, prediction.interval = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading the `library(forecast)` documentation it seems that:

```
forecast(tsHolt, 12)
```

works as well!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Here is how to solve it: -

```
library(forecast)

# Creating a time series object

Data_ts <- ts(Data, frequency = 12)

fit = HoltWinters(Data_ts)

# Forecasting using Holt-Winters

pred = forecast::forecast(fit, h = 12) # forecasting for the next 12 months.

plot(pred)
```

The critical part in the code is to use: -

**forecast::forecast**(fit, h = 12)

If you are using various libraries, then the forecast's library functions gets masked. Hence, we have to specify that we must use *forecast function* from *forecast library*.